# Computation of first variational equation of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, vector-analysis

The textbook(Ordinary Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems, Gerald Teschl) says:

For the differential equation

$\dot x$ = $f(x)$, $\;x(0) = x_0$ where $f \in C^k(M, R^n)$ where $M$ is open subset of $R^n$,

Let $\phi(t, x_0)$ be solution of the equation.

Then, linearized equation of $\phi(t,x_0)$ is $\dot \phi(t,x_0) = A(t)\,\phi(t,x_0)$
where $A(t) = df_{\phi(t,x_0)}$.

However, I can't understand the  notation of $df_{\phi(t,x_0)}$ and confused when calculating example.

For example, when $\phi(t, (1,0)) = (\cos(t), \sin(t))$ and 
$\dot x_1 = -x_2 + x_1(1-x_1^2-x_2^2),\; \dot x_2 = x_1 + x_2(1-x_1^2-x_2^2)$

Then, $f(\phi(t,(1,0)) = (-\sin(t), \cos(t))$.

Textbook says, in this case, 
$A(t) = \begin{bmatrix} -2\cos^2(t) &-1+\sin^2(2t) \\ 1-\sin(2t) & \cos(t)\end{bmatrix}$

How do I derive this equation?
I thought $df_{\phi(t,x_0)}$ means the gradient of $f(\phi(t,x_0))$, but in this case, $\nabla f(\phi(t,x_0)) = \begin{bmatrix} -\cos(t)\frac{\partial t}{x_1} &-\cos(t)\frac{\partial t}{x_2} \\ -\sin(t)\frac{\partial t}{x_1} & -\sin(t)\frac{\partial t}{x_2} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \cot(t) &-1 \\ 1 & -\tan(t)\end{bmatrix}$

Is it, $df_{\phi(t,x_0)} \neq \nabla f(\phi(t,x_0))$? or I calculated wrong?

I have very poor understanding about general topic about vector calculus and having trouble with this. Help me please...

Comment: You've done the operations in the wrong order, and the answer you get doesn't make sense (what 
is the meaning of $\frac{\partial t}{x_1}$?). You need to calculate the gradient of $f(x_1, x_2) = (-x_2+x_1(1-x_1^2-x_2^2), x_1+x_2(1-x_1^2-x_2^2))$ and then plug in $\phi(t, (1, 0))$.

Comment: Also, it is not a good idea to move on to the study of ODEs and dynamical systems if you feel that your understanding of calculus is poor. Calculus is extremely important to this field.

Comment: Oh, that is it.. I was confused about that.. the function takes $t$, but I have to calculate the gradient of $f$. The gradient should be calculated before putting $t$ in, and just putting $t$, we get gradient, but I thought it was gradient about the function defined by $t$, and it led to compute like this. my English is bad that if you understood why I was confused. Anyway, Thanks a lot.

Comment: The gradient of a function $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2$ would not even be a $2\times 2$ matrix, but a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$.